# Tsi107 PowerPC Host Bridge Vs Processor

Tags: microcontroller, memory, interrupts, microprocessor, interface

I a confused regarding the difference between a powerPc host bridge and a processor. According to the host bridge datasheet, it can be programmed, and it has interrupt generation and handling, and some registers for configuration. As far as I know, a processor does almost the same tasks, and it has external memories I/O, etc. What is the difference between both? Secondly, the bridge contains the CPU so does every CPU system has such an IC that manages all these things for it, as far as I have seen the CPU diagrams show a direct connection with the memory/IO, etc as shown below. What's the need for this IC then? Kindly help me clear up this confusion.
[image]

Comment: Its a design choice for a particular CPU architecture as to whether to integrate the CPU and peripheral handling into a single chip, or to split into multiple chips, whether the periperal chip is called the chipset, northbridge or host bridge. Its a tradeoff in terms of the size of the CPU die, and how the interconnects between the CPU die and off CPU functionality work, and how multiple CPUs and different peripheral configurations are supported.

Comment: Traditionally, a major motivating factor was to increase yields for the CPU die, by reducing its size by not having the functionality on a single die.

Comment: A second major motivation factor was to avoid having to invest in new packaging and PCB tooling for ever greater pin counts, as more and more peripherals were needed and more busses converted to P2P. By splitting the peripheral access over 2-3 chips, rather than just the CPU, you reduced the number of pins needed by any one of those chips, enabling the use of lower pin count, less dense packages to be retained.

Comment: Are you sure your host bridge can be "programed" in the same sense as a CPU can be? I think it's more likely that it can be programed in the sense that it can be "configured", and not the it can execute an arbitrary sequence of instructions like a CPU.

Comment: yes the bridge consists of some configuration registers which are used to do the configurations etc.

Comment: Right - so then it has no similarity at all with a processor.

Comment: @kam1212 - Hi, I see you created & accepted an answer by copying several comments. That can be acceptable (since answers shouldn't be written as comments) but the comments *must* be attributed to their author(s). Following the protocol explained on Meta [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127781) & [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252303), I added links to the original comments & user profile(s), to comply with the CC BY-SA license. I have also set it to "Community Wiki" since the answer is an aggregation of work by other site members, so the answer's writer shouldn't gain points.

Comment: @SamGibson okk will make sure next time I mention them correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered in comments on the question, by *[user1937198](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/200588/user1937198)*:

[Comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/674845/tsi107-powerpc-host-bridge-vs-processor/695546#comment1797127_674845):

> Its a design choice for a particular CPU architecture as to whether to integrate the CPU and peripheral handling into a single chip, or to split into multiple chips, whether the peripheral chip is called the chipset, northbridge or host bridge. It's a tradeoff in terms of the size of the CPU die, and how the interconnects between the CPU die and off CPU functionality work, and how multiple CPUs and different peripheral configurations are supported.

[Comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/674845/tsi107-powerpc-host-bridge-vs-processor/695546#comment1797128_674845):

> Traditionally, a major motivating factor was to increase yields for the CPU die, by reducing its size by not having the functionality on a single die.

[Comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/674845/tsi107-powerpc-host-bridge-vs-processor/695546#comment1797133_674845):

> A second major motivation factor was to avoid having to invest in new packaging and PCB tooling for ever greater pin counts, as more and more peripherals were needed and more busses converted to P2P. By splitting the peripheral access over 2-3 chips, rather than just the CPU, you reduced the number of pins needed by any one of those chips, enabling the use of lower pin count, and less dense packages to be retained.

<sub>Reposted unaltered, with attribution, in accordance with the [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) license by following [this approach](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252303) to synthesize an answer-from-comments.</sub>